# Android - How to animate multiple views together and sequentially at the same time?

Tags: android, animation, kotlin, android-transitions, objectanimator

Let's say I have views A, B, C and D.

I need to animate `View A` bringing its height from zero to a `CONSTANT_HEIGHT` (that I have) as well as its alpha from zero to 1.

Immediately after `View A`'s animation, I need to animate `View B`'s alpha from 0 to 1, `View C`'s alpha from 0 to 1 and call a method called `setChecked` on `View D` (a custom checkbox). `setChecked(checked: Boolean, animate: Boolean)` method already has animation if param `animate` is `true`.

So, the first animation would be: `View A` -> `alpha` to `1.0f` together with `height` to `CONSTANT_HEIGHT`.

Immediately after conclusion of first animation, second animation would start and it would be: `View B` and `View C` `alpha` to `1.0f` and `View D` call `setChecked(checked: true, animate:true)`, all playing together/concurrently (in parallel).

How can I achieve this?

I've tried through `Transition`, `AnimatorSet`, etc but I have been failing in all attempts. Could someone guide me on how to solve this problem?

**EDIT**:

Trying through Transition:

```
   val tras1 = TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(statusLayout, Fade(Fade.IN))

   firstLine.layoutParams.height = 200
   firstLine.alpha = 1.0f
   firstCheckBox.setChecked(true, true)
```

For instance, here I used `Fade(Fade.IN)` as the transition but I also alter the height of a view (`firstLine`), right? Then, how do I schedule another transition after this one? After the last transition, do I need to close it (or do anything) ?

**EDIT2**:

I am trying the following but the animations are not playing smoothly (in fact they are changing abruptly as if there was no animation at all. Same effect as just calling `view.alpha = 1.0f`.

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(statusLayout, Fade(Fade.IN))

firstLine.alpha = 1.0f

TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(statusLayout, ChangeBounds())

firstLine.layoutParams.height = 200

TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(statusLayout, Fade(Fade.IN))

myLabel.alpha = 1.0f
```

Comment: yep, [Transition](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html) is the way you should follow

Comment: @pskink, but to which view? In the example, it gives the root view group. Does this mean it won't animate the root view group but rather it will animate only any of its children declared below the `beginTransition`? Could you add an example regarding my case?

Comment: read `Apply a transition without scenes` section

Comment: @pskink, I read as you suggested. Look at my edit, please.

Comment: so call another `beginDelayedTransition()` when the first `Transition` ends... what kind of problems do you have with it?

Comment: @pskink, Take a look at Edit 2, please.

Comment: `"so call another beginDelayedTransition() when the first Transition ends... what kind of problems do you have with it?"` calling `beginDelayedTransition` 3 times in a row does not do that

Comment: Hmm.. when do I know that the first Transition has ended? Could you provide some example code?

Comment: see `android.transition.Transition` API javadocs

Comment: @pskink, I've looked extensively and man I have no idea, sorry. in iOS, it's soooo simple to do this animation of multiple views. Why does Android complicate things so much...

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and found this approach online:

**The Layout XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="48sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**The Java File:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //your existing code here

    int[] textViewIDs = {R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3,R.id.text4,R.id.text5,R.id.text6};
    int delayBetweenAnim = 300;

    for (int i = 0; i < textViewIDs.length; i++) {
        Animation fadeAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade);
        fadeAnimation.setStartOffset(i * delayBetweenAnim);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(textViewIds[i]);
        textView.startAnimation(fadeAnimation);
    }
}
```

**The fade.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
           android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
           android:duration="500" />
```

**NOTE:** Although this does the job, I am not sure about the efficiency of this code. I only create hobby applications for myself and this seems to suffice my needs well enough. However, I would advise you to look into even more efficient codes. Experts can probably comment about this code's drawbacks below.